# Where does the Not Before value come from in an Azure SAML response

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

I have a SSO from Azure that is not working and the debug code is saying that the Not Before failed. 01/20/2023 03:20 aa EST

Where does this come from and how do I find it in Azure?

After some debugging I can add this info

```
My request sent this IssueInstant="2023-01-26T09:55:06Z"

The response return with Not Before 01/26/2023 12:54 aa EST failed
                         Not On Or After 01/26/2023 01:59 aa EST Passed
```

I changed my code to substract three hours from the IssueInstant and my request sent

```
IssueInstant="2023-01-26T06:01:52Z

The response return with Not Before 01/26/2023 12:54 aa EST failed
                         Not On Or After 01/26/2023 01:59 aa EST Passed
```

Why is the IssueInstant being ignored?
Where is the Not Before coming from?
The server is set for PST and the request is going to Azure.

Comment: Sounds like the `nbf` (not before) is causing the error. It's a claim that is sent contained inside the azure jwt token which holds a unix timestamp. When your token is validated one of the validation steps is to check whether the current time falls in the `nbf` and `exp` (expiration time). It seems like it fails on that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do understand that but how do you fix it. Is there a setting in Azure where the time is set.

Comment: You can't set the time of the token, but it should be valid. Issue could be the date time on the machine you're testing it on or a problem with the code.

Comment: This is my understanding, the nbf is calculated to be approximately a hour before the naf (Not On Or After) value and it uses the naf to create the nbf. If this is correct where does the naf come from? Is it the IssueInstant in the Request?